# How to compare simple date with datetime in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

On my project, I created an option for the user to search by date, but in my database, all the inserts are in DateTime format (yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s), while the search is made only with a simple date(yyyy-mm-dd) input.
Is there any way I can compare these two values, so the user can find all the inserts on the given date?

Comment: If you're omitting the hour, minute and seconds from a timestamp, date-based searches can still work, they will simply be "inclusive" (i.e. if you searched for "2021-11-23", that would include all timestamps from "2021-11-23 00:00:00" to "2021-11-23 23:59:59"). Unless you're trying to do a string comparison, your date-based search should still function correctly. What have you tried to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use eloquent whereDate with format Y-m-d

```php
YourModel::whereDate('created_at','2021-11-24')->get();
```

or without model

```php
DB::table('your_table')->whereDate('created_at','2021-11-24')->get();
```

Comment: I was using only a simple where(), that's why it wasn't working. Thanks for the assist!